# why all products in database is not appear in output (only one product list is appear) i want all list. i share a picture of that table

Tags: python, mysql, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxyvq.png)   its a python code
in output only one list is appear . i want all lists
please help me to solve this

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql import connector


def get_all_products():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='R#@26rads26',
                                  host='127.0.0.1',
                                  database='gs')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM gs.products"
    cursor.execute(query)
    response = []
    for (product_id, name, uom_id, price_per_unit) in cursor:
        response.append({
            'product_id': product_id,
            'name': name,
            'uom_id': uom_id,
            'price_per_unit': price_per_unit
        })
        cnx.close()
        return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_all_products())
```

Comment: You are printing the return value of `get_all_products`, i.e. the list `response`, so that's the only list printed. Which other lists would you like to print?

Comment: This looks like an indentation problem. `cnx.close()` is inside your for loop, as well as your return

Comment: cnx.close() inside the for loop .not working. its give error

Comment: I want to print all lists in the product table, but there are only the first  list is printed in the table.([{'product_id': 1, 'name': 'rice', 'uom_id': 1, 'price_per_unit': 25.0}]) its a first list . I want all listes  in the table

Comment: After the cursor.execute(query), you need to do something like data=cursor.fetchall() and then iterate over data

Comment: i do  data=cursor.fetchall() and output give none. it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Moving your final lines outside of the for loop should fix your issue:

```py
    for (product_id, name, uom_id, price_per_unit) in cursor:
        response.append({
            'product_id': product_id,
            'name': name,
            'uom_id': uom_id,
            'price_per_unit': price_per_unit
        })
    # The following lines should not have been inside the for loop
    cnx.close()
    return response
```

Comment: cnx. close() and return response inside the loop not working

Comment: Can you provide the error so I can help you?

Comment: it's not an error. my output are: [{'product_id': 1, 'name': 'rice', 'uom_id': 1, 'price_per_unit': 25.0}]

Process finished with exit code 0
(I want all listes in the product table). (I attach an image in my question)

Comment: If you have only one product it is because you return too soon. That is why I suggested correcting the position of the return. You tried my code but it gives you an error, what is the error?

Comment: All product lists are in the output. thank you so much :)